# index.php don't load with laravel and wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, wamp

I'm newbie. So I got a problem with a laravel app. I can access any url like www.test.com/something but it browser returns "This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" any time when I try to open www.test.com/ or www.test.com/index.php

I'm using Wamp server 2.5

httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test/public"
      ServerName test.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On


   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   </IfModule>
```

got this line in the routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented.
When I insert something like

```
echo "test"; exit;
```

in the very beginning of the index.php, it works fine and the message appears.
The trick is that another project with the same settings works properly.
Any ideas?

EDIT: The problem was in the BLADE comments like {{-- smthg --}}. Solved by replacing on ordinary html comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your computer that the test.com domain is hosted on your server you can do that by adding it to your host file